# Convert a math equation in string format to something workable in Python3

Tags: python, string, math, python-3.x, exponentiation

So I have a function that takes a math equation in string format, and a list of numbers.

The purpose of the function is to apply that function to each number (an exponent function), and return the result.

For example, I am trying to pass "x**4" to it, and the list [4,3,2]

The end result, of course, would be [256, 81, 16]

How do you convert the string to a math equation while also keeping in mind that the string could be anything from "x**2" or "x**3".

Comment: You will need a lookup table. This table will store all valid operations you intend for your program to carry out. When you get the string, you parse it by removing all non alphanumeric characters (strings), then you use the lookup table to decide what operation needs to be done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [eval function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) , and use a list comprehension. This requires you know the var name ahead of time. If you don't, parse it then use this.

```
>>> operation = "x**4"
>>> num_list = [4,3,2]
>>> [eval(operation) for x in num_list]
[256, 81, 16]
```

Comment: `eval` is a builtin: it doesn't come from the `math` library.

Comment: I tried this exact code in Python command line to test it out, and I ended up getting:
[True, False, False]

When I try it in my own code:

`def getYTable(function, xlist):

 result = []
 result.append(eval(function) for x in xlist)

 return result

def Main():
 ylist = getYTable("x**2", [1,2,3])
 print(ylist)`

I end up getting [<generator object <genexpr> at 0xb72afd74>]


What is going on here? eval is a bit new to me.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.
`def getYTable(function, xlist):
 #Write your implementation here

 result = []

 for x in xlist:
  result.append(eval(function))

 return result`

Answer (score 0):

Depends how complicated you need it to be. Could you use the map builtin like:

```
x = [4, 3, 2]

def exp4( val ):
    return val ** 4

map( exp4, x )
```

You define the functions you need and apply them as an when. You've not said if you need an abilty to pick functions dynamically and it presumes an itterable (list in this case).

Comment: Drat, I somehow missed the last line of the question, C.B.s answer looks good.